# Identify image encoding and convert it to a real image in python

Tags: python, image

Currently I have the following problem: I get an array of image data (a large vector). I do neither know the size of the image, only the formula for the size `(2^n*2^m)` nor know the encoding of the image (jpeg, j2k, lossy 12bit jpeg or similar). One array I know the encoding looks like:

```
[-1000,  -888,  -884,  -883,  -884,  -886,...-850,  -852,  -854,  -854]
```

Here I can simply reshape it into the form I want to have (in this case its the square root of the length) and afterwards convert it into an image I can view with

```
pixel_values = numpy.asarray(pixel_values).reshape(512, 512)
pl2 = pylab.imshow(pixel_values, cmap=pylab.cm.bone
```

But now I have another array:

```
[65534, 57344,     4,     0,     0,     0, 65534, 57344,  7652,     1, 20479, 20991, 10496,     0,...35286, 23076, 34407, 36383, 56252, 65370,   217]
```

Here I can not use the square root or something similar (I know that the images are always like `(2^n*2^m)`, and I don't know how I can transform this data into a real image I can view. How can I find out the encoding of this data and the size in python?

Answer (score 0):

1. To determine the size of the image, I don't think there is a better approach that simply by trial and error. First we determine the image sizes compatible with the expression `(2^n, 2^m)`,

   ```
   import numpy as np

   vect_len = len(pixel_values)
   min_size = 256 # e.g. minimal size acceptable for one of the dimensions

   npm = np.log2(vect_len)  # this is n+m
   if not npm % 1:
       # n+m is an integer
       for n in range(1, npm):
             p = npm - n
             if 2**n < min_size or 2**p < min_size:
                 continue
             print(n,p)
   # (256, 2048)
   # (512, 1024)
   # (1024, 512)
   # (2048, 256)
   ```

   Then, for each of the possible image sizes, we reshape the `pixel_values` array and plot the result until it looks right. If it is a colour image, there would also be a third dimension of size 3 for RGB channels.
2. If you can visualise you image simply by reshaping the input vector, that means that it contains directly the values for each pixel and we don't care about the encoding of the image (it was already decoded). Indeed, say jpeg would store the discrete cosine transform (DCT) coefficients in the .jpeg file, j2k stores the wavelet transform coefficients, etc. This is not something you want to get into, and the approach is to use the appropriate library for each format.

Comment: In the second case (my problem case) the image size is 4*9151, but I know that it has to fit into this scheme, therefore it has to be compressed somehow. How can I find out if it is a j2k- or jpg-image I have the data from? For decoding I can use the libraries, of course.

Comment: @arc_lupus I edited the answer to account for RGB images.   My point is data stored as jpeg, would look like metadata + decomposition coefficients, with a different size than that of the image. So simply looking at a vector of number wont allow you to decode anything. If you have a file, you can can read it with the jpeg library, everything else is pretty much hopeless. 9151 is a prime number, so I'm not sure what you can do with that. The most likely that the problem lies in the way you obtain this vector.

Comment: I get the vector from a DICOM-file, and the library tells me that that is the data for the picture in the DICOM file

Comment: @arc_lupus Since DICOM is a standard file format, I would assume that somewhere in the metadata, it should indicate the size of the image array. Besides, you shouldn't have to do any image decoding if you are using say pydicom (or a similar library). The encoding of the file (jpeg, etc) does not matter from the user point of view.

Comment: pydicom fails in this case, telling me compressed data is not supported. That is the reason why I have to do it by hand.

Comment: @arc_lupus From comments at the [pidicom wiki](https://code.google.com/p/pydicom/wiki/ViewingImages)  "As noted on the main page, pydicom does not decode compressed pixel data. It is very complex to do in a pure-python package, although hopefully one day it will be implemented. A work-around is to first uncompress the images using another toolkit. For example, dcmtk has command line tools for this. (e.g. http://support.dcmtk.org/docs/dcmdjpeg.html) "

Comment: I used that tool, too, but I want to have all together in one script (and I still can't open the decompressed images, too)

Comment: At this point, I think it's best to contact pydicom developers and see how you can contribute toward the support of a compressed format there and what is necessary to make it happen. It looks like it is a complex problem, and it is unlikely you will find a simple solution to it on SO.